# API to use Nginx HTTP Parser

Tags: c++, http, c++11, nginx, c++14

If I am building a custom web server and really want to avoid writing code for parsing the HTTP requests can I use some other HTTP parser such as the Nginx HTTP parser (any other parser is completely fine, I suggested this because of its speed) to parse the HTTP request for me?

If yes then could someone explain with an example how I can extract the parsed values from the HTTP request? I am planning to write this in C++.

Thank you!

Comment: Unlikely you could reuse nginx parser because nginx is a quite specialized application and its code is bound tightly to the whole nginx framework. Also, it's pure C.

Comment: Thanks! I have been trying to understand the parser and it seems rather complicated to me as well.. I think they wrote it with some sort of meta state machine writer software like ragel

Comment: I'd suggest yo use an HTTP lib there's a bunch of them out there.

Comment: What capabilities do you need from HTTP parser? HTTP/1.0, HTTP/1.1, HTTP2, websockets and other related things? In what environment (OS, other libs/frameworks) your application is supposed to function?

Comment: @user3159253 Could you suggest one that is easy to use? I am asking because I feel like it will save me some time if I go by your experience :)

Answer (score 4):

NGINX provides parser written in C, these are files *http_parse.c* and *http_parser.h*, provided by the [parser](https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser).

By defining callbacks, one can easily use the parser. Here is an extract from my current project:

```
http_parser_settings parser_settings;
http_parser parser;

http_parser_init(&parser, HTTP_BOTH);
parser_settings.on_message_begin = [](http_parser *parser)
{
    // Here goes the implementation
}
parser_settings.on_url = [](http_parser* parser, const char* at, size_t len)
{
    // here goes the implementation
}
parser_settings.on_header_field = [](http_parser* parser, const char* at, size_t len)
{
    // here goes the implementation
}
parser_settings.on_header_value = [](http_parser* parser, const char* at, size_t len)
{
    // here goes the implementation
}
parser_settings.on_headers_complete = [](http_parser* parser)
{
    // here goes the implementation
}
parser_settings.on_body = [](http_parser* parser, const char* at, size_t len)
{
    // here goes the implementation
}
parser_settings.on_message_complete = [](http_parser* parser)
{
    // here goes the implementation
}
```

To start the parser use

```
size_t read = http_parser_execute(&parser, &parser_settings, message, length);
```

To parse URL there is `http_parser_parse_url()`.

Comment: nginx is not nodejs